How to extract firmware from STM32F437
I found a board with STM32F437II chip on it. Apparently it has built-in flash memory to store the firmware. Is there a way of extracting this firmware for further analysis and reverse engineering?
There are only two sets of pins on this part of the board. (I didn't send the rest of the board, because it is not related.)


If the code protection is not set you can get the object code by using ST's software and STLINK hardware. Clones of the STLINK V2 start at a couple dollars and the software is free.
If it's a commercial product, then the code protection will almost certainly be enabled and you will not easily be able to get the object code out. (Of course there is likely someone who can, but that's a different, and unwelcome, subject).

You'll certainly never get the "object code" from the part, protection or not, since that typically refers to the output from the compiler before linking, not present in the binary executable. I think you mean "op codes" or "machine code" (raw assembler).

@Lundin I call the hex file 'object code'. "Intel hexadecimal object file format" ,  which you can certainly generate from the binary dump. Have they gone and redefined that?

I don't think I have heard that before. Intel hex is still alive and kicking, but most of the time referred to as "executable" or some such, I believe. Object code has a common meaning as the middle stage between compilation and linking (most compilers spit out some manner of .obj files). Regardless, you won't be getting either of those out of a programmed MCU. Unless you have a tool that translates the raw binary to some ASCII format like Intel hex.

@Lundin That's exactly what you'd get from the ST tool - .hex or .bin . Of course the former won't likely be identical to the compiler output because Intel hex has various line lengths and there can be gaps, but it will be functionally identical resulting in the same bits in the flash being programmed.

The average MCU released during the past 20 years or so comes with a "copy cat protection" feature as standard, which can be optionally enabled. If enabled, a hardware lock prevents anyone from reading out the flash until it has been erased. Meaning you would have lose all of the contents in order to access the flash from the outside.
This security feature is not necessarily enabled, but in a commercial product it is very likely. "Reverse engineer the program by reading out the flash" is mostly a thing of the past (1990s).
